# Wrapping multiple rows into one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this dataset in mysql which for a particular `subject` i want them to be collapsed down into one row. The number of rows to wrap around varies. A typical dataset make look like this:

Column Names:
`Sitting Date | Subject | Exam Part 1 | Exam Part 2 | Assignment Part 1 | Assignment Part 2 | Practical Part 1 | Practical Part 2 | Project Part 1 | Project Part 2 | Overall Mark | Result | Credits`

Results:

`052012  Business Information Systems    0.00    0.00    51.0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    42 F    10.00`

`052012  Business Information Systems    29.0    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    42 F    10.00`

What I'm trying to do is wrap them into one row like:

`052012 | Business Information Systems | 29.00 | 0.00 | 51.0 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 42 | F`

How would i form such a query in mysql? My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM exam_results WHERE sdate = :sdate AND studno = :studno
```

Comment: Please explain the way to the values in your single row display. Is it the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CONCAT_WS` in MySQL :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' | ', `Sitting Date`, `Subject`, <...>) FROM `table`
```